# How can I add a podspec dependency only to iphone device and not a simulator using Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have a podspec(of MyParentModule, which MyApp depends on), where I need to add a dependency (MyModule which MyParentModule depends on) but only for a iOS device, but not a simulator.

```
s.dependency 'MyModule' #Adds pod to both device and simulator
```

I tried to add the dependency utilising LD flags and framework search path.

```
s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS[sdk=iphoneos*]' => '$(inherited) ${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/MyModule', 
    'OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphoneos*]' => '$(inherited) -framework MyModule'
}
```

and use MyModule in the MyParentModule as such

```
#if !targetEnvironment(simulator)
import MyModule
#endif
```

and this works correctly on the simulator but this results in a crash on a device where I use/ call it.

```
Referenced from: '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F947DD90-5ADD-4DE3-B2D0-9ED12BFD5CF8/MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyParentModule.framework/MyParentModule'
Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/swift/MyModule.framework/MyModule' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F947DD90-5ADD-4DE3-B2D0-9ED12BFD5CF8/MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyModule.framework/MyModule' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F947DD90-5ADD-4DE3-B2D0-9ED12BFD5CF8/MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyParentModule.framework/Frameworks/MyModule.framework/MyModule' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/MyModule.framework/MyModule' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/MyModule.framework/MyModule' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F947DD90-5ADD-4DE3-B2D0-9ED12BFD5CF8/MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyModule.framework/MyModule' (no such file), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F947DD90-5ADD-4DE3-B2D
```

Comment: IMO you are overcomplicating it. I would include it in all cases, but make sure that `MyParentModule` calls the `MyModule` code in case of real device, and some simulated code in case of simulator (e.g. use adapter pattern). This ensures that both real device and simulator do the same work, and get similar results - one in real way, one in simulated way

Comment: @sfgblackwarkrts The issue is MyModule is not really MyModule but a third party module that does not support x86_64. But I want to keep supporting simulator (without the features of MyModule, of course)

Comment: Hey @Aswath, do you have any new findings on the topic?